# Get in SCSS Mixin inside @each vars from next array entrie

Tags: css, sass, styles, stylesheet, scss-mixins

I want to higher my quality standards of frontends and build today a little helper for the background image part:

.html

```
<div></div>
```

.scss

```
@mixin backgroundImage($path: '/assets/images', $fileName: null, $supports: null, $fileType: '.jpg', $unitType: 'px', $startFrom: 0) {
    @each $res in $supports {
        @media only screen and (min-width: $startFrom / 720 / 1280 / 1920 / 2560 / Last not need) and (max-width: $res#{$unitType}) {
            background-image: url("#{$path}#{$fileName}-#{$res}#{$fileType}");
        }
    }
}

div {
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50%, 50%;
    background-color: navajowhite;
    @include backgroundImage($fileName: 'background', $supports: (720, 1280, 1920, 2560, 3840), $startFrom: 480);
}
```

I tryed to create a stackblitz, but realized then, that i cant upload there images. So if you need a demo to test, please create in root where the index.html will be a folder named `assets/images/` and place there 5 files named `background-720`, `background-1280` etc...

Ok the point is that i need here: `(min-width: $startFrom / 720 / 1280 / 1920 / 2560 / Last not need)` to get in every `@each` the number of `$supports` of the last `@each`. Just in the first `@each` i need to use the `$startFrom`

I know its confusing. But I never wrote complex SCSS Mixins before. I hope someone can help me with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i got it now... The final working code:

```
@mixin resBgImg($path: '/assets/images/', $fileName: null, $resolutions: null, $fileType: '.jpg', $unitType: 'px', $startFrom: 0)
    @for $i from 1 through length($resolutions)
        $min: $startFrom
        @if $i > 1
            $min: nth($resolutions, $i - 1)
        $max: nth($resolutions, $i)
        @if $i == length($resolutions)
            @media only screen and (min-width: $min + 1+$unitType)
                background-image: url("#{$path}#{$fileName}-#{$max}#{$fileType}")
        @else
            @media only screen and (min-width: $min + if($i > 1, 1, 0)+$unitType) and (max-width: $max+$unitType)
                background-image: url("#{$path}#{$fileName}-#{$max}#{$fileType}")
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your only problem was that you're missing a slash between the path, as it's resolving to `/assets/imagesbackground-$sz.jpg`, and I also don't think you need `$startFrom`, as you can just add that to the `$supports` array.

Here's what I changed it to and it seems to be working just fine:

```
@mixin backgroundImage($path: '@/assets/images', $fileType: '.jpg', $unitType: 'px', $fileName: null, $supports: null, $startFrom: 0) {
  @each $size in $supports {
    @media only screen and (min-width: $startFrom#{$unitType}) and (max-width: $size#{$unitType}) {
      background-image: url("#{$path}/#{$fileName}-#{$size}#{$fileType}");
    }
  }
}
```